# Fetch nested array Firebase + SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

i trying to parse nested array in my doc in Firebase storage.
I have a function to fetch data and document structure. Can you help me to update my function?)

[image: here is my document]

[image: Order Model]

[image: function code]

Comment: Can I suggest to use code snippets instead of screenshots for your source code? This will make it easier for people to answer your question, as they will be able to re-use your code. It is OK (and actually quite useful) to use screenshots to show the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do yourself a favour and don't map data manually from Firestore to Swift.

Firestore supports the Swift Codable protocol, which makes things *a lot* easier.

### Using Codable w/ Firestore

Here's a short snippet that shows how to adapt your code:

```swift
struct Order: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String
  var number: Int
  var status: String
  var clientName: String
  // ...
}
```

```swift
class OrdersViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var orders = [Order]()
  @Published var errorMessage: String?
  
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
  
  public func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
      listenerRegistration = nil
    }
  }
  
  func subscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
      listenerRegistration = db.collection("orders")
        .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            self?.errorMessage = "No documents in 'orders' collection"
            return
          }
          
          self?.orders = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
            let result = Result { try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Order.self) }
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let order):
              if let order = order {
                // An Order value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
                self?.errorMessage = nil
                return order
              }
              else {
                // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
                // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
                self?.errorMessage = "Document doesn't exist."
                return nil
              }
            case .failure(let error):
              // An Order value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
              switch error {
              case DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context):
                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
              case DecodingError.valueNotFound(_, let context):
                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
              case DecodingError.keyNotFound(_, let context):
                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
              case DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let key):
                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(key)"
              default:
                self?.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
              }
              return nil
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
  
}
```

While this might look more complicated than your code, the key line is this:

```swift
try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Order.self)
```

The rest of the code performs some error handling (which you should absolutely do), and thus adds a bit of noise.

### Mapping arrays

Using Codable makes mapping arrays quite simple. You can use any type that is `Codable` itself inside your arrays.

So for your order items, use the following:

```swift
struct OrderItem: Codable {
  var cost: Int
  var name: String
}
```

And then update the `Order` struct as follows:

```swift
struct Order: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String
  var number: Int
  var status: String
  var clientName: String
  var items: [OrderItem]
  // ...
}
```

That's it - everything else will be handles automatically. See [Mapping arrays](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#mapping-arrays) in my article for further details.

### Resources

For more details, please refer to [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#error-handling) and [SwiftUI: Mapping Firestore Documents using Swift Codable - Application Architecture for SwiftUI & Firebase](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/). The article also explains how to [customize the mapping](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#customising-the-mapping) using `CodingKeys`.

Comment: I used your materials from article 
I had some problems like these ones.

self.orders = try document.data(as: MedcineModel.self)

Error is "Cannot assign value of type 'MyModel?' to type [MyModel]
@PeterSmith

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your struct into a variable how

```
var dataStruct = [Struct]()
```

After that, you need check your *fetchOrder* method, one solution are similar to:

```
func fetchOrder() {
db.collection("orders").order(by: "items").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            return
        } else {
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            
            for eachDoc in documents {
                let data = eachDoc.data()
                guard let items = data["items"] as? [String] else { continue }
                let itemArray = generateMovieItemsWith(items: items)
                self.dataStruct.append(itemArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear about what your problem is, I am assuming the array data is failing to parse. The problem is obvious, its not `as! [Any]`.
Try using `as! [Any:Any]` because it's not a list of objects, it's a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a subcollection inside the document. For me much easier to handle the queries.(eg. collection(Orders).document(orderid).collection(orderedFood).getDoc...)
But if you want nested objects here is a link:

[https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firestore-to-swift-models-with-complex-types-enums-and-arrays-282893affb15]